# How to enable multi-tab synchronization for Firebase Web Version 9 (modular)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase JavaScript Modular Web Version 9 SDK.

And I have enabled offline persistence [as per these docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#web-version-9) using this: `enableIndexedDbPersistence(db)`.

Now I want to keep data synced between multiple open browser tabs.

I thought I could do that in the PersistenceSettings object like this: `enableIndexedDbPersistence(db, { synchronizeTabs: true })`.

But it turns out that `synchronizeTabs` property does not exist on the PersistenceSettings object.

The [docs for the PersistenceSettings object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.persistencesettings) do not have the `synchronizeTabs` property listed, but they do have a `forceOwnership` property with a description that mentions:

> This cannot be used with multi-tab synchronization

This leads me to believe that multi-tab synchronization is possible. Because it is telling me that multi-tab synchronization cannot be used together with `forceOwnership`. I do not care about `forceOwnership` but I still want multi-tab synchronization.

So how do I enable multi-tab synchronization for the JavaScript Web Version 9 SDK?

Comment: It seems that your goal is not included in the Firebase documentation. I suggest requesting it as a feature in this [link](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly use [`enablemultitabindexeddbpersistence`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#enablemultitabindexeddbpersistence) to achieve what you want, instead of passing the `PersistenceSettings` object.